# Create line from points while keeping attribute information

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

Is there a way (in QGIS) to create a line from a series of points, while maintaining (at least) a column of the attribute information for each point (ie one column containing the values for a certain variable for all points)? I've been able to create lines out of the points using the 'points to path' vector creation tool, but the attribute table of the resulting line has only two cells, listing the beginning and end values: I want to keep the values for each point from which the line has been constructed.

I'm using QGIS 3.4.4 on macOS.

Comment: A column for each point's attributes? You would need a dynamic number of columns because the line length might vary. You could put them all in one column - rather like some of the import tools do (OGR's OSM import puts additional tags in an "other_tags" columns. Or you keep the points and reference them - eg. each point could have a field that references the parent line.

Comment: What if you have 10,000 points?  Would your resulting table have 10,000 columns? You may be able to associate the line you've created in one table with all of the point records in another table using a one-to-many relationship, but once again, that could get really unwieldy unless your particular scenario has limits on the number of points. Oasis montaj, a commercial geophysics mapping package, has the concept of a line with many data points along it. Basically each line is a time series with a number of asynchronous channels along it. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @winwaed I think what I actually would want is a row for every point's value for a certain attribute, not a column - my mistake.

Comment: @marcp see above, but in any case it would be a relatively small number of points - the test I'm trying to do now is using 82 points.

Comment: You could do a spatial join between the line and the point after the line creation

Comment: Agree JR - that is what I was getting at with the reference on the point objects. This is how OSM handles things like "features that are parts of a river"

Comment: There's an insurmountable (AFAIK) problem with spatial joins in this situation: Points to Path creates a single output line.  In Matthew's example, he has 82 points (each with it's own unique attribute info), all of which touch the output line. A spatial join will not work because all 82 are equally valid inputs (which point value is assigned to the line?)  Alternatively, splitting the single line at each point and then spatially joining point to line will also fail because each point will touch 2 line segments; to which line segment shall each point value be assigned - upstream or downstream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matthew, there's a terrific QGIS plugin that does exactly what you want.  I've used it successfully for some time.  It's called *Points to Paths* (note the plural *Paths*), `EDIT: *Points to Paths* has been updated to QGIS 3.x.` and is only available at QGIS version 2.x (don't stop reading - hear me out!).  It is far more capable than the 3.x *Points to Path* (note the singular *Path*) that you've tried without success.

Since *Points to Paths* hasn't been updated yet for 3.x, you'll have to install a separate QGIS 2.x version on your computer, but I think that it's well worth the small effort.  Fortunately, 2.x and 3.x seem to play well together.

Older Mac QGIS installs can be downloaded here:

https://qgis.org/downloads/macOS/

and older Windows installs here:

https://qgis.org/downloads/

After installing 2.x (I use 2.18.28, the last 2.x release), install the *Points to Paths*  plugin.  A few notes on its use:

1. "Point Group Field": Use this if your point data is organized into unique groups, such as specific airline flights.
2. "Point Order Field": This field contains the point sequence that, in turn, dictates the resulting line direction.  Using the airline flight example, this would be a time stamp for each point along the flight's route.  Think GPS breadcrumbs.
3. If your "Point Order Field" is formatted as text, and it contains date and/or time info (such as 2019-10-01 19:24:30) you need to specify that format in the "Date Format" fill-in box.  Using my year-month-day hour:minute:second example, you would enter **%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S**  I don't know why month and day are lower-case.
4. Check the "Line per Vertex" box.   This is critical!  When checked, a separate line segment is created for each unique "Point Order Field" value, and ***(this is where the magic happens)*** the output line shapefile includes two attribute fields containing the beginning and ending values, respectively, from the point layer's "Point Order Field".  You can now join the line layer to the point layer, and then create/calculate additional line layer fields, populating them from the point layer` (airspeed, altitude...).  Voila - your line layer now carries the correct point attribute info!

This is a really useful tool (there's even no Arc Desktop equivalent), and I hope it is quickly added to the 3.x plugin repository.  Until then, however, I'm keeping a separate 2.x installation on my computer.

**EDIT:**

Here's a screenshot of the *Points to Paths* tool in 2.18.28, with the all-important *Line per vertex* option highlighted:

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you so much! After a bit of fiddling around with the settings I have been able to create the line I needed in QGIS 2, but when I try to open the file in QGIS 3 it doesn't show up on the map (although the layer is in the layers panel above everything else and the attribute table is correct). Do you know if I need to do anything else in order for the line to work as desired in QGIS 3?

Comment: Try restarting QGIS 3.x, then load the line layer by itself in QGIS, Do the lines now display?

Comment: The line works now, thank you!

Comment: Great!  One additional note: In my step 4, I mention that two attribute fields are created by Points to Paths.  They are named "begin" and "end".  Unfortunately, those are reserved words in the Arc Desktop universe, so you might want to create two additional fields, calculate them equal to "begin" and "end", then delete "begin" and "end".  I don't know if they are reserved words in QGIS; I get rid of them just to be safe.

Comment: @StuSmith I don't seem to have the "Line per vertex" box on qgis 2.18 with the latest release of the plugin on windows 7. Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: @user25976 Are you sure that you're using the "Points to *Paths*" tool, and not the "Points to *Path*"?  I've added a screenshot to my original answer that depicts the "Line per vertex" option in "Points to *Paths*".  I'm not sure when that tool/option was added to QGIS, but it is there at 2.18.28, and I first started using it while running Windows 7.

Comment: Made an upgrade to the plugin to support QGIS 3.0 in a PR https://github.com/chiatt/pointstopaths/pull/7. Feedback welcome as I do not know the normal expected plugin behaviour (not using it) @StuSmith Does not hesitate to comment

Comment: @ThomasG77 Thanks, I sent you a msg on Github.

Comment: @StuSmith yes--I'm sure. I don't have that last checkbox on the interface using QGIS 2.18 on Windows 7 (the rest is the same). I've been using this plugin without that option for years--really could have used it too. QGIS 3 upgrade looks promising though!

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming all points making a line have the same information in the attribute table**, it is also possible to perform a spatial join as J.R. mention in the comments. This does not perfectly answer the question, since the information the points contain has to be the same. But people are stumbling over this question (as I did) because they look for a solution to join points with the same information in the attribute table.

So the faster way is the following:

1. Use the tool `Points to path` in QGIS 3 to create a line out of the points.
2. Use the tool `Join Attributes by Location` to join the attribute tables of the origin layer and the newly created layer containing the lines.